# Return a float from a 64-bit assembly function that uses x87 FPU

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, masm, x87

I am trying to make a program that calculates equations (what equation doesn't matter currently) that use 64-bit registers, floats, and coprocessor instructions. Unfortunately I don't know how to access the final outcome of the equation as a float. I can do:

```
fist qword ptr [bla]
mov rax,bla
```

and change the function type to *INT* and get my value, but I cannot access it as a FLOAT. Even when I leave the result in ST(0) (the top of the coprocessor stack) it doesn't work as expected and my *C++* program gets the wrong result. My assembly code is:

```
public funct
.data
bla qword ?
bla2 qword 10.0
.code
funct PROC
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
push rbx

mov bla,rcx
fild qword ptr[bla]

fld qword ptr [bla2]
fmul st(0), st(1)
fist dword ptr [bla]
pop rbx
pop rbp
ret
funct ENDP
END
```

My *C++* code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" float funct(long long n);
int main(){

    float value1= funct(3);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You really should look at using SSE2+ to perform floating point calculations in 64-bit code. Floating point values must be returned in the XMM0 register according to the [Microsoft 64-bit calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7572ztz4.aspx)

Comment: Does it still count as using FPU commands? I noticed XMM0 registers, but I am not sure they fit into the restrictions I am at. Basically I want a program that is called from C language that runs in 64 bits and does floating point calculations, maybe I misunderstood the task.

Comment: SSE2 (lowest common denominator supported on all the AMD and Intel 64-bit processors) is the new way to do floating point calculations. No it is not technically an FPU. I don't know anything about your task/assignment, I'm just making the observation that using the X87 instructions for floats is now pretty much frowned upon in 64-bit mode. You'll need to pop the result out of the X87 FPU store it in memory and then use an SSE instruction to move it to the XMM0 register. You could use the `movss` instruction to move a 32-bit float from memory to the XMM0 register.

Comment: [MOVSD](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_204.html) can be used to move a scalar double (64-bit float) to XMM0.

Comment: fst qword ptr [bla]
movsd xmm0, qword ptr[bla]

i added this but it still doesn't work T.T, value1 shows as 0,000....

Comment: Probably because in your C++ code that you say `float funct(long long n);`. float is 32-bit, double is 64-bit. Your function and your question suggest you want 64-bit (and `movsd` is for scalar doubles). So I think you should change to `extern "C" double funct(long long n);` and `double value1= funct(3);`

Comment: If you are actually trying to return 32-bit floats then you'll want to use `fstp dword ptr [bla]` `movss xmm0, dword ptr[bla]` , We use `dword ptr` and `movss` (move scalar single where a scalar single is a 32-bit float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, and so is your code. I'll present a few ideas using the x87 FPU, and *SSE* instructions. The usage of x87 FPU instructions is discouraged in 64-bit code, and *SSE*/*SSE2* is preferred. *SSE*/*SSE2* are available on all 64-bit AMD and 64-bit Intel x86 processors.

---

### 32-bit float in 64-bit code using x87 FPU

If your question is *"How do I write 64-bit assembler code that uses 32-bit floats using the x87 FPU?"* then there your *C++* code looks fine, but your assembler code needs some work. Your *C++* code suggests the output type of the function is a 32-bit float:

```
extern "C" float funct(long long n);
```

We need to create a function that returns a 32-bit float. Your assembler code could be modified in the following fashion. I am keeping the stack frame code and the push/pop of *RBX* in your code, since I assume you were just giving us a minimal example and that your real code is using *RBX*. With that in mind the following code should work:

```
public funct
.data
ten REAL4 10.0                     ; Define variable ten as 32-bit (4-byte float)
                                   ; REAL4 and DWORD are both same size. 
                                   ; REAL4 makes for more readable code when using floats
.code
funct PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp                   ; Setup stack frame
                                   ; RSP aligned to 16 bytes at this point
    push rbx

    mov [rbp+16],rcx               ; 32 byte shadow space is just above the return address
                                   ; at RBP+16 (this address is 16 byte aligned). Rather 
                                   ; than use a temporary variable in the data section to 
                                   ; store the value of RCX, we just store it to the 
                                   ; shadow space on the stack.
    fild QWORD ptr[rbp+16]         ; Load and convert 64-bit integer into st(0)
    fld [ten]                      ; st(0) => st(1), st(0) = 10.0
    fmulp                          ; st(1)=st(1)*st(0), st(1) => st(0)
    fstp REAL4 ptr [rbp+16]        ; Store result to shadow space as 32-bit float
    movss xmm0, REAL4 ptr [rbp+16] ; Store single scalar (32-bit float) to xmm0
                                   ; XMM0 = return value for 32(and 64-bit) floats
                                   ;        in 64-bit code.

    pop rbx
    mov rsp, rbp                   ; Remove stack frame
    pop rbp
    ret
funct ENDP
END
```

I've commented the code, but the thing that might be of interest is that I don't use a second variable in the *DATA* section. The 64-bit Windows Calling Convention requires the caller of a function to ensure the stack is aligned on a 16-byte boundary and that there is a 32 byte [shadow space](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/) (AKA *register parameter area*) allocated before making a call. This area can be used as a scratch area. Since we set up a stack frame, *RBP* is at `RBP+0`, the return address is at `RBP+8` and the scratch area starts at `RBP+16`. If you weren't using a stack frame then the return address is at `RSP+0`, and the shadow space would start at `RSP+8` We can store the result of our floating point operation there instead of in the *QWORD* you labelled *bla*.

It is a reasonable idea to unwind the floating point stack so nothing remains on it before we exit our function. I use the FPU floating point functions that pop the registers after we are done using them.

The [64-bit Microsoft calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx) requires floating point values to be [returned in XMM0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7572ztz4.aspx). We use the *SSE* instruction *MOVSS* to move a scalar single (32-bit float) to the *XMM0* register. That is where the *C++* code will expect that value to be returned.

---

### 32-bit float in 64-bit code using SSE

Building on the ideas in the section above, we can modify the code to use *SSE* instructions with 32-bit floats. An example of such code is as follows:

```
public funct
.data
ten REAL4 10.0                     ; Define variable ten as 32-bit (4-byte float)
                                   ; REAL4 and DWORD are both same size. 
                                   ; REAL4 makes for more readable code when using floats
.code
funct PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp                   ; Setup stack frame
                                   ; RSP aligned to 16 bytes at this point
    push rbx
    cvtsi2ss xmm0, rcx             ; Convert scalar integer in RCX to 
                                   ;    scalar single(float) and store in XMM0
    mulss xmm0, [ten]              ; 32-bit float multiply by 10.0 store in XMM0
                                   ; XMM0 = return value for 32(and 64-bit) floats
                                   ;        in 64-bit code.
    pop rbx
    mov rsp, rbp                   ; Remove stack frame
    pop rbp
    ret
funct ENDP
END
```

This code removes the usage of the x87 FPU by using SSE instructions. In particular we use:

```
    cvtsi2ss xmm0, rcx             ; Convert scalar integer in RCX to 
                                   ;    scalar single(float) and store in XMM0
```

[CVTSI2SS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SS.html) converts a scalar integer to a scalar single (float). In this case the 64-bit integer value in *RCX* is converted to a 32-bit float and stored in *XMM0*. *XMM0* is the register we'll be placing our returned value into. *XMM0* to *XMM5* are considered [volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx) so we don't need to save their values.

```
    mulss xmm0, [ten]              ; 32-bit float multiply by 10.0 store in XMM0
                                   ; XMM0 = return value for 32(and 64-bit) floats
                                   ;        in 64-bit code.
```

[MULSS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MULSS.html) is an SSE instruction that is used for SSE multiplication using scalar single (float). In this case *MULSS* would do XMM0=XMM0*(32-bit float memory operand). This would have the effect of doing 32-bit floating point multiply of *XMM0* by the 32-bit float of 10.0. Since *XMM0* also contains our final result we have nothing more to do but properly exit the function.

---

### 64-bit double float in 64-bit code using x87 FPU

This is a variation on the first example, but now we are using 64-bit floats also known as the `double` type in *C++*, `REAL8` (or `QWORD`) in assembler, and a `scalar double` in *SSE2*. Since we are now using `double` as the return type we have to modify the *C++* code to be:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" double funct(long long n);

int main() {    
    double value1 = funct(3);

    return 0;
}
```

The assembly code would look like:

```
public funct
.data
ten REAL8 10.0                     ; Define variable ten as 64-bit (8-byte float)
                                   ; REAL8 and QWORD are both same size. 
                                   ; REAL8 makes for more readable code when using floats
.code
funct PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp                   ; Setup stack frame
                                   ; RSP aligned to 16 bytes at this point
    push rbx

    mov [rbp+16],rcx               ; 32 byte shadow space is just above the return address
                                   ; at RBP+8 (this address is 16 byte aligned). Rather 
                                   ; than use a temporary variable in the data section to 
                                   ; store the value of RCX, we just store it to the 
                                   ; shadow space on the stack.
    fild QWORD ptr[rbp+16]         ; Load and convert 64-bit integer into st(0)
    fld [ten]                      ; st(0) => st(1), st(0) = 10.0
    fmulp                          ; st(1)=st(1)*st(0), st(1) => st(0)
    fstp REAL8 ptr [rbp+16]        ; Store result to shadow space as 64-bit float
    movsd xmm0, REAL8 ptr [rbp+16] ; Store double scalar (64-bit float) to xmm0
                                   ; XMM0 = return value for 32(and 64-bit) floats
                                   ;        in 64-bit code.

    pop rbx
    mov rsp, rbp                   ; Remove stack frame
    pop rbp
    ret
funct ENDP
END
```

This code is nearly identical to the x87 code using 32-bit float. We are using *REAL8* (same as *QWORD*) to store a 64-bit float and use [MOVSD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSD.html) to move a 64-bit double float (scalar double) to *XMM0*. *MOVSD* is an *SSE2* instruction. It is important to return the proper size float in *XMM0*. Had you used *MOVSS* the value returned to the *C++* function would likely be incorrect.

---

### 64-bit double float in 64-bit code using SSE2

This is a variation on the second example, but now we are using 64-bit floats also known as the `double` type in *C++*, `REAL8` (or `QWORD`) in assembler, and a `scalar double` in *SSE2*. The *C++* code should use the code from the previous section so that *double* is used instead of *float*. The assembler code would be similar to this:

```
public funct
.data
ten REAL8 10.0                     ; Define variable ten as 64-bit (8-byte float)
                                   ; REAL8 and QWORD are both same size. 
                                   ; REAL8 makes for more readable code when using floats
.code
funct PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp                   ; Setup stack frame
                                   ; RSP aligned to 16 bytes at this point
    push rbx
    cvtsi2sd xmm0, rcx             ; Convert scalar integer in RCX to 
                                   ;    scalar double(double float) and store in XMM0
    mulsd xmm0, [ten]              ; 64-bit float multiply by 10.0 store in XMM0
                                   ; XMM0 = return value for 32(and 64-bit) floats
                                   ;        in 64-bit code.
    pop rbx
    mov rsp, rbp                   ; Remove stack frame
    pop rbp
    ret
funct ENDP
END
```

The primary difference from the second example is that we use [CVTSI2SD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SD.html) instead of *CVTSI2SS*. *SD* in the instruction means we are converting to a scalar double (64-bit double float). Similarly we use the [MULSD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MULSD.html) instruction for multiplication using scalar doubles. *XMM0* will hold the 64-bit scalar double (double float) that will be returned to the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the address of the result as parameter:

**main.c:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

extern "C" void funct(long long, float*);

int main ( void )
{

    float value1 = 0;           // float = DWORD ("double" would be QWORD)!
    funct(3, &value1);
    printf ("%f\n",value1);

    return 0;
}
```

**callee.asm:**

```
.data
    bla qword ?
    bla2 qword 10.0

.code
funct PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rbx

    mov bla,rcx
    fild qword ptr[bla]         ; -> st(1)

    fld qword ptr [bla2]        ; -> st(0)
    fmul st(0), st(1)
    fstp dword ptr [rdx]        ; pop the first value
    ffree st(0)                 ; pop the second value

    pop rbx
    pop rbp
    ret
funct ENDP

END
```

Comment: Why are you making a stack frame in the callee, and esp. why are you saving/restoring `rbx` when you don't even touch it?  Win64 calling convention puts the first two args in `rcx` and `rdx`, I assume?  Also, you could prob. use `fmulp` and avoid the `ffree`.  If the integer didn't have to be 64bit, you could use `fld qword [bla2]` / `fimul dword [bla]` / `fstp dword [rdx]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I always try to be as close as possible to the MCVE of the OP. If there is a sillyness, I assume a faulty reduction of the original code. I usually don't correct it, if it isn't an obvious mistake and doesn't handicap the clearness of my example.